# Xcode 11 - color highlight of a variable in printed text (C language)

Tags: c, xcode, syntax, colors, highlight

Is there a way to highlight a placement of variable in a printed text? I cannot find any syntax highlight coloring anywhere in Xcode 11.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void volume_of_cylinder(void) {
    printf("Please enter the radius of the cylinder:\n");

    double radius;
    scanf("%lf", &radius);

    printf("Please enter the height of the cylinder:\n");

    double height;
    scanf("%lf", &height);

    double volume;
    volume = M_PI*height*(radius*radius);

    printf("A radius of %.4lf and a height of %.4lf correspond to a volume of %.4lf.\n", radius, height, volume);
}

int main(void) {
    volume_of_cylinder();
    return 0;
}
```

For instance, in this simple code, I'd like to color highlight the "`%.4lf`" in the last `printf` function.

Thank you